# How to use apply_parallel on db calls

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo, pandarallel

I was using apply_parallel function from pandarallel library, the below snippet(Function call) iterates over rows and fetches data from mongo db. While executing the same throws me **EOFError** and a mongo client warning as given below

Mongo function:

```
def fetch_final_price(model_name, time, col_name):
    collection = database['col_name']
    price = collection.find({"$and":[{"Model":model_name},{'time':time}]})
    price = price[0]['price']
    return price
```

Function call:

```
final_df['Price'] = df1.parallel_apply(lambda x :fetch_final_price(x['model_name'],x['purchase_date'],collection_name), axis=1)
```

MongoClient config:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(host=host,username=username,port=port,password=password,tlsCAFile=sslCAFile,retryWrites=False)
```

Error:

***EOFError: Ran out of input***

Mongo client warning:

***"MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only "***

How to make db calls in parallel_apply??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "MongoClient opened before fork" warning also provides [a link for the documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing), from which you can know that in multiprocessing (which pandarallel base on) you should create  MongoClient **inside your function** (`fetch_final_price`), otherwise it likely leads to a deadlock:

```
def fetch_final_price(model_name, time, col_name):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        host=host,
        username=username,
        port=port,
        password=password,
        tlsCAFile=sslCAFile,
        retryWrites=False
    )
    collection = database['col_name']
    price = collection.find({"$and": [{"Model": model_name}, {'time': time}]})
    price = price[0]['price']
    return price
```

The second mistake, that leads to the exception in the function and the following EOFError, is that you use the brackets operator to a `find` result, which is actually an iterator, not a list. Consider using [`find_one`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update%20one#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) if you need only a first instance (alternatively, you can do `next(price)` instead of indexing operator, but it's not a good way to do this)

```
def fetch_final_price(model_name, time, col_name):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        host=host,
        username=username,
        port=port,
        password=password,
        tlsCAFile=sslCAFile,
        retryWrites=False
    )
    collection = database['col_name']
    price = collection.find_one({"$and": [{"Model": model_name}, {'time': time}]})
    price = price['price']
    return price
```